# Assign a unit to a variable in a function

Tags: function-construction, units, chemistry

I have the following input:

```
PVW[V_, T_] := (R*T/(V - b)) - (a/(V^2))
```

Where I have already defined R as the molecular gas constant with its corresponding units and a and b are constants with their proper units.

My question is, if it is posible to define, that V and T also have units, so that when I put, for example, PVW[1.5,300] the results comes with the correct units.

Comment: Input the pressure and temperature with units as well? `PVW[Quantity[1.5,"Liters"],Quantity[300,"Kelvin"]`, if the other units are set up properly, should suffice.

Comment: yes, but is there a way to define it previously? so that I don't have to write everytime Quantity[]?

Comment: For context (since the OP neglected to provide it): this is the van der Waals equation of state, relating pressure, volume and temperature.

Answer (score 3):

You may use [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html).

```
PVW[V_, T_] :=
 With[{qV = Quantity[V, "Liters"], qT = Quantity[T, "Kelvins"]},
  (R*qT/(qV - b)) - (a/(qV^2))
  ]
```

Hope this helps.